# Probability and Combinatorics

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am trying to solve example 4.15 [here](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=60DFDKKQ9Z4C&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=five%20manufacturers%20produce%20a%20certain%20electronic&source=bl&ots=PlUCAq6STw&sig=3i3OKJ8eWK7pnTPVFMV08hE6bhI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMI85_b8ZqHxwIVlFOOCh0hTQIF#v=onepage&q=five%20manufacturers%20produce%20a%20certain%20electronic&f=false) but think the total number of outcomes in the solution is incorrect. This is my reasoning.

We have 3 that qualify as best three, say BBB, and 2 as bad say OO.

Thus, the total outcomes can be calculated as follows:
0 bad : This will be 1 as only one way to choose the best three
1 bad : This will be 3 ways. 'OBB' is one example and can be arranged in 3 ways.
2 bad : 3 ways.

Thus, the total outcomes according to me should be 7, not 10. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't link to your question, links get broken; copy the question text in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flaw in your reasoning is in "1 bad : This will be 3 ways"

Correct # of ways for 1 bad, 2 good = ${2\choose 1}{3\choose 2}$ = $2\cdot3$ = 6

The *full* expression, case wise, without any shortcuts, would be ${2\choose 0}{3\choose 3} + {2\choose1}{3\choose2} + {2\choose2}{3\choose1} = 10$

But why add up different cases ?

You directly get it as choosing any 3 out of the total of 5, viz. ${5\choose3}$ = 10

Answer (score 0):

The book is right and your reasoning has missed out adding the 1 way you can have all good and the 3 ways you can have 1 good 2 bad =4.